# Solution for SSH File transfer between 2 Servers

Tags: networking, ssh, server

When i ping with packet size 10000 to Server B from Server A the icmp response takes 18ms whereas when i transfer file of10Kb which is of same size i get 100ms response. Why it takes more time transferring the File?

Comment: Why would it be the same? They're are completely different protocols.

Comment: It's actually Using SSH to transfer the file

Comment: Is there any solution to reduce time may be less then 100ms. Because transferring file is taking more the 100ms. I believe it's the size of the packets we need to reduce if we want to lower the time. Isn't so??

Comment: The bandwidth is 1Gbps between servers and there is no other device or node between 2 servers.

Answer (score -1):

ping time and bandwidth are different , you have check the bandwidth of the network of your servers and firewall of them